# mercurial update caused errors in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, tortoisehg

I am using Tortoise HG on windows for a java project. I tried to revert to an older version of my code by clicking "update" on the proper revision in the UI screen while eclipse was closed.

When I opened up eclipse lots of errors showed up!!!

The error log yells about failing to import mercurial keyring.
Right now I am having lots of weird compilation errors that weren't there before!!

I tried refreshing and cleaning my project but nothing helps!

Anyone else encountered a proble like that?

Comment: Did you do something, like merging, when updating to the older version?

Comment: You seem to have different issues. If even an 'hg update -C' did not fix the compilation errors, you could re-clone your repo and start fresh. That would also require you to re-enter your passwords and possibly fix the keyring problems at the same time.

Comment: I have recloned from server but the issues persist!
I believe this is a pure eclipse problem.
IT also shouts about $HOME variable. 
Which is weird

Comment: Fixed. There was a case problem in folders/packages names. For some reason those spelling differences can't be committed